# Better way of getting First Date of Week by passing Week number of the year in c#?

Tags: c#

I have written following method in order to return first Date of week by passing week number of year and year, I consider Monday as first day of week. I am wondering if there is any better way I can calculate this. Here is my code;

```
 public static DateTime GetFirstDateOfWeekByWeekNumber(int year, int weekNumber)
    {
        var date = new DateTime(year, 01, 01);
        var firstDayOfYear = date.DayOfWeek;
        var result = date.AddDays(weekNumber * 7);

        if (firstDayOfYear == DayOfWeek.Monday)
            return result.Date;
        if (firstDayOfYear == DayOfWeek.Tuesday)
            return result.AddDays(-1).Date;
        if (firstDayOfYear == DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
            return result.AddDays(-2).Date;
        if (firstDayOfYear == DayOfWeek.Thursday)
            return result.AddDays(-3).Date;
        if (firstDayOfYear == DayOfWeek.Friday)
            return result.AddDays(-4).Date;
        if (firstDayOfYear == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
            return result.AddDays(-5).Date;
        return result.AddDays(-6).Date;
    }
```

Comment: Get first monday of current week?

Comment: It looks like @GSerg posted what you're looking for. If you don't do that, you should at least turn that into a `switch` instead of all the `if`s.

Comment: @MaxPoshusta How switch is better than if? As I remember, people suggest avoiding switch case. Can you give me any argument that tells switch is better than if's, thanks?

Comment: I don't know why you'd avoid `switch/case`.  Just do whatever makes your code the most readable.  In your case, it would be using `switch/case`.

Comment: Maybe what you're thinking about is using `switch/case` for polymorphism.  That's bad design.  See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/147227/20458

Comment: @Learner It's been argued whether `switch` is faster or slower than `if`, at the end of the day the difference is negligible in most user cases. The real thing with the `switch` is that, in my opinion, its much more readable.

Comment: _I consider Monday as first day of week_  - the `DayOfWeek` enum starts with Sunday.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace that if/else construct, you can just calculate using the underlying  enum values. The enum starts with `Sunday = 0`, `Monday = 1`, so in order to get your Monday-based values, you need to shift it around by one. You can do that in the following way:

```
int delta = -((int)firstDayOfYear + 6) % 7;

// and then just apply the delta
return result.AddDays(delta).Date
```

As a site note, don’t use multiple `if`s with a mutally exclusive condition in sequence. In your example, if the week day was `Monday`, the construct would still check the value against *every single* condition there. But if you used a proper `if/else if/else` structure, then it would only do the first check and then jump to the end. Using a `switch` statement also avoids this as the branch to take is evaluated in a single step.